# RxAndroid blocks UI thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-android, rx-java2

I have simple job which is selecting data using GreenDao. Also i want show ProgressWheel, but this job blocks UI thread.

```
    showLoader();

    DataManager.getInstance(this).getQuestions(0, 800)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(QuestionUtils::shuffleAnswers)
            .subscribe(this::onFinishLoad);
```

And

```
    public Observable<List<Question>> getQuestions(int offset, int limit) {
           return Observable.fromCallable(() -> daoSession.getQuestionDao().queryBuilder()
            .offset(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .build().list());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blocks because of the order of your operations.

```
DataManager.getInstance(this)
        .getQuestions(0, 800)
        .map(QuestionUtils::shuffleAnswers)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::onFinishLoad);
```

should solve it. Else you would subscribe data and map them after.

If you want to finish the loader onec your data are emitted you can use action in your subscribe method and process the loading in your emitted nextData.

```
 .subscribe (nextData -> {},  error -> {}, () -> doCompletedStuff())
```